# Pandas reads partial content

Tags: pandas, csv, python-3.6

### Here is my csv

```
"Merchantname1, Address, http://url.com/to/his/website.html 
"Merchantname2, Address, http://url.com/to/his/website.html
"Merchantname3, Address, http://url.com/to/his/website.html
```

### Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('/path/to/csv', usecols=['Page url'])
print(df)
```

### Result

```
                                              Page url
0    https://url.com/to/his...
1    https://url.com/to/his...
2    https://url.com/to/his...
```

It just ignores the rest of the link. I need the entire url and not ...
Can someone point the mistake? Thanks...

Comment: related and probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26277757/pandas-to-html-truncates-string-contents and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351968/how-to-display-full-non-truncated-dataframe-information-in-html-when-convertin

Comment: Thanks @EdChum, saved my day....