# Avoid (buggy) line break in Jupyter Notebook when displaying pandas dataframe when string contains a dash

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I would like do `display(df)` in a notebook cell. The `df` contains a column named 'id' with a string like "A-1234-5678". I would like to avoid the automatic line break on each "-" in the id column and have everything displayed in one line.

I think this happens when the number of columns does not fit the display width and a scrollbar is introduced. This effect does not happen with a "." instead of "-" as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':["A-123456-7894", "B-123456-7894"]})

for i in range(0, 5):
    df[str(i)] = None

display(df)

for i in range(5, 20):
    df[str(i)] = None

display(df)
```

produces

[image]

The [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351968/how-to-display-full-non-truncated-dataframe-information-in-html-when-convertin) to set `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', -1)` does not resolve my issue.