# Put a set of datas (URLS) in an empty dataframe Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

i am **scraping** a series of URL's with this code :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
url = 'https://www.welcometothejungle.com/fr/jobs? 
page=1&refinementList%5Bprofession_name.fr.Tech%5D%5B%5D=Data%20Science'
path = '/Users/jdkj/desktop/chromedriver 3'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome((path), chrome_options=options)
html = driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article/div[2]/header/a['href']")

for elem in elems:
    urls = elem.get_attribute("href")
    print(urls)
```

This returns the correct results that i want to see, the problem is that when i try to put this "urls" in my empty dataframe "df1"  with the following code :

```
df_test = df1.append({'URLS' : urls}, ignore_index = True)
df_test.head()
```

It does not show me the urls that i want (it doesn't return an error but the result doesn't really make sense)

I am beginning at python so there is probably some simple answer to my question i guess, i hope i was clear

Comment: Can you please include more information about the error you receive when running the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are overwriting the `urls` variable and then appending to the `DataFrame` only the last scraped URL. Move the `df1.append` statement to inside the `for` block:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame()
url = 'https://www.welcometothejungle.com/fr/jobs? 
page=1&refinementList%5Bprofession_name.fr.Tech%5D%5B%5D=Data%20Science'
path = '/Users/jdkj/desktop/chromedriver 3'
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome((path), chrome_options=options)
html = driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
elems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//article/div[2]/header/a['href']")

for elem in elems:
    url = elem.get_attribute("href")  # <--- get the url from the <a> tag
    df1 = df1.append({'URLS': url}, ignore_index=True) # <--- add the url to the dataframe in the URLS column
```

Comment: Almost there ! it indeed returns the outpu row by row, but strangely it doesn't return the whole URL, for example : the original url => https://www.welcometothejungle.com/fr/companies/cdiscount/jobs/stage-data-analyst-f-h_bordeaux-33_CDISC_85y0eQQ , the OUTPUT url => https://www.welcometothejungle.com/fr/companie...

Comment: Try putting `pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)` after your `import pandas`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/25352191.

Comment: @Hichhich the problem could be the way that you are scraping your elements. The a tag doesn't have any class or ID that you could use that to scrap? And please edit your question with the original URLs and the output URLs

Comment: yes of course, sorry, newbie on this forum :D