# Python pandas dataframe "for loop" output, transform dictionary values to columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Absolute newbie ;)

Current Input (note that some of the input below relies on other code which I ran before this, not included here):

```
data = []

vid_list = list(primary_variants['vid'].unique())
for vid in vid_list:
    report_info = get_reports_with_vid([vid]).rename(columns={"xe": "xe_id"})
    og_rqs = report_info["rq"].apply(lambda x: x.split("-")[0])
    report_info = report_info[og_rqs != 'RQ53']
    vid_info = get_vid_warn_info(report_info[["xe_id", "vid"]].to_dict("records"))
    vid_info = report_info.merge(vid_info, on=["xe_id", "vid"], how="left")
    conf_status = dict(vid_info["confirmation_status"].value_counts())
    data.append({'conf_status': conf_status})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Current Output:

```
                                                       conf_status  
0  {'confirmation_not_necessary': 16, 'might_need_confirmation': 2}     
1  {'confirmation_not_necessary': 1}                                    
2  {'confirmation_not_necessary': 3}                                    
3  {'confirmation_not_necessary': 6}                                    
4  {'confident_call': 2}                                                
5  {'confirmation_not_necessary': 1791, 'might_need_confirmation': 48}
```

Question: Ideally, I really want rearrange the dataframe output like this (below), so I can copy results directly into a spreadsheet from the dataframe output. How can I accomplish this output?

```
        vid     conf_not_nec    might_need_conf    conf_call
0  3014790      16              2        
1  12246762     1
2  7989296      3
3  2385739      6
4  14560093                                        2
5  1901209      1971            48
```

Answer (score 0):

this can be confusing for a newbie!

#### You've actually got 2 questions in there.

#### Firstly:

You're getting the output you expected it's just wrapping itself around the terminal/console.
Note that you can see a backslash after the first column header ''. That's the give-away.

If you set the pandas width with:

```py
pd.set_option('display.width', 200)
```

*note using pd, and not df, it's a global pandas setting
More info can be researched in this answer:
[How can I display full (non-truncated) dataframe information in HTML when converting from Pandas dataframe to HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25351968/how-can-i-display-full-non-truncated-dataframe-information-in-html-when-conver)

You can have a play around with pd.width, pd.column_maxwidth and a few other settings.
Have a look through the options available in pandas:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

#### For your second question:

Why is it adding the extra columns?
Here:

```py
conf_status = dict(vid_info["confirmation_status"].value_counts())
```

You're assigning the conf_status as a dictionary type. Which has a key and a value. Then you're appending that dictionary to the 'conf_status' column right below it:

```py
data.append({'vid': vid, 'conf_status': conf_status})
```

You might be able to just simplify the assignment of the variable with:

```py
conf_status = vid_info["confirmation_status"].value_counts()
```

Give those a try and let me know how you go!

Comment: Just a note here for new players:
If you throw in a **print(type(variablename))**
It will tell you what your variable type is. When things are doing funny stuff, it can be useful to know.