# Storing a clickable link inside a numpy chararray

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a numpy chararray populated with items and I need for each item to be a clickable link in the html. But the href tag is displaying as text when I do this:

```
grid = np.chararray(shape=[2,2]).astype('|S55')

item = "<a href='#'>%s</a>" % str(item_number) 
grid[1,1] = item
```

I don't know that it matters, but I'm using pandas to create a dataframe and then sending it to the django template as html using the to_html() method.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=grid.astype(str),    # values
    index=side,    # 1st column as index
    columns=header   # 1st row as the column names
)
table = df.to_html()
```

How can I put a link inside a chararray such that it's clickable when rendered on the page?

Comment: What string do you want to put in the chararray?

Comment: Something like <a href="/part_number/1234/">1234</a>

Comment: Related: [Insert a link inside a pandas table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20035518/190597).

Comment: `'<a href="/part_number/{0}/">{0}</a>'.format(item_number)`?

Comment: @unutbu I saw the related post, but I'm not clear how to apply this solution as I am creating the numpy chararray and then using pandas to build the dataframe by passing the data. I guess I'm unclear on how to apply this solution.

Comment: @Goyo puts the text into the cell, but it's not clickable.

Comment: I think you're solution actually does work, but only if I iterate over the pandas dataframe rather than converting it to html. This suggests I have an incomplete understanding of my issue.

Comment: @wmfox3: [That link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20043785/190597) shows you need `df.to_html(escape=False)` instead of `df.to_html()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.to_html(escape=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) to prevent the conversion of characters like `<`, `>` and `&` to HTML sequences (like `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

item_number = 99
grid = np.chararray(shape=[2,2]).astype('|S55')
item = "<a href='#'>%s</a>" % str(item_number) 
grid[1,1] = item

df = pd.DataFrame(grid.astype(str), columns=['a', 'b'])
print(df.to_html(escape=False))
```

yields

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th></th>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>0</th>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <td></td>
      <td><a href='#'>99</a></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]