# Formatting pandas html table with hyperlinks in cells

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a dataframe which I convert to html format in Pandas with to_html() function.
The format of the table itself is:

```
<table border="2" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: center;">
      <th>AF</th>
      <th>Enlaces Forms</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>60</td>
      <td>https://forms.office.com/Pages/ResponsePage.aspx?id=uIG64v4DfECWofS8D1Eu</td>
    </tr>
       .
       .
       .
```

what I would like to do is to replace the part where the forms link is to include some title and hiding the whole link to make it more readable.
I know in html is with href="{link}" title=... but I do not know how to implement it here.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a link inside a Pandas table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035518/insert-a-link-inside-a-pandas-table)

Comment: Much appreciated, but the link are rendered properly. My issue is that I cannot shorten the links with a specific name let's say "LINK". When I introduce the title in the html tag it just simply display the whole link